# Why is my newly created package not installing properly? Did I create a conflict?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I am on Debian Lenny and I had nginx 0.7.65 from lenny-backports installed. I needed the `uwsgi` module so I added the `deb-src` for lenny-backports and did `apt-get source nginx`. This grabbed the 0.7.67-3.

I followed this guide to a T: http://brandonkonkle.com/blog/2010/sep/14/django-uwsgi-and-nginx/ and then did dpkg -i nginx*.deb as per the instructions.

It doesn't seem like it replaced 0.7.65 because I get this:

```
(Reading database ... 27253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace nginx 0.7.67-3~bpo50+1 (using nginx_0.7.67-3~bpo50+1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nginx ...
Preparing to replace nginx-dbg 0.7.67-3~bpo50+1 (using nginx-dbg_0.7.67-3~bpo50+1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nginx-dbg ...
Setting up nginx (0.7.67-3~bpo50+1) ...
Trying a soft restart
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nginx-dbg (0.7.67-3~bpo50+1) ...
```

And, if I try to `/etc/init.d/nginx stop` and start again, it wont obey. I think I may have caused a conflict of some sorts?

The `dpkg -i` was supposed to install 0.7.67, and I have 2 deb files after I did the dpkg-buildpackage: nginx_0.7.67-3~bpo50+1_i386.deb and nginx-dbg_0.7.67-3~bpo50+1_i386.deb

Where did I go wrong? Could someone explain why nginx doesnt obey at all now? I can't stop it or start it. If I go into `aptitude` it tells me that 0.7.67 is the installed version.

Comment: Just to help you triage the problem: on the Debian side, you do have nginx 0.7.67 installed correctly, so your issue is with nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall an issue in debian's packaging a while back where they changed the pid location.  It is also possible you changed a shared library that is causing the existing nginx to not find the code in the newly relocated address.  You could do:

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

and see what the error is on the line after start-stop-daemon

Worst case, find the pid of nginx and do a kill (or if it is stuck, kill -9)

At that point, you should be able to restart nginx normally.

Comment: I did a `pkill nginx` then `sudo nginx` and that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. test test configuration

   $ sudo nginx -t
2. try run nginx without /etc/init.d/nginx

   $sudo nginx
3. Read log:

   $sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog

Comment: This is what I get: http://pastie.org/private/jhediiavcqj3mq4pwde6w after `sudo nginx`.